# Grub problem booting problem at fresh install of Centos

Tags: centos, grub, system-installation

I've Windows 7 installed on my PC. I would like to install Centos and remove Windows 7 completely.

After burning a Centos 6.2 on a DVD, and restarting the machine, I got the `grub>` window.

I can not install Centos at all: I just see the grub prompt.

However, on my laptop, the same DVD is giving me the graphical installation options. How can I install Centos on my PC?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Go into your bios settings and turn off UEFI boot mode